# Symfony uploaded files not reading on azure

Tags: php, azure, symfony, azure-web-app-service

I have 2 questions.

I have deployed a Symfony 3.4 app on Azure MySQL + PHP web app. I have some forms where user can upload files. images, pdfs etc.

First Question:

When I deployed site I had 300+ files in my symfony app upload directory and I was not able to upload files from the forms. When I logged into Azure I found an error there which is.

```
ERROR

There are 349 items in this directory, but maxViewItems is set to 299. You 
can increase maxViewItems by setting it to a larger value in localStorage.
```

So I removed all the images and tried to upload the image again and got success in uploading image. So how can I remove the localStorage limit from azure?.

Second Question:

The uploaded images are not appearing on website. how can I show them on website?

My upload directory is

```
/web/uploads/media/default/0001/01/
```

Here I am uploading image from forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my second question. The issue was in my web.config file and I fixed it by adding a rule to allow file types as follow.

```
    <rule name="RewriteAssetsToPublic" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^(.*)(\.css|\.woff|\.woff2|\.tff|\.js|\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.ico|\.pdf|\.jpeg)$" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="web/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
```

And my this issue solved all files are being upload.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using chrome browser, go to your website

1. open developer tools (F12)
2. in the console, run window.localStorage['maxViewItems'] = 350

Answer (score 1):

There is a [blog](https://azureappservices.blogspot.com/2018/06/azure-some-filesfolders-are-not-visible.html) explained the reason of this issue that was caused by the Kudu Service Web [code](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/master/Kudu.Services.Web/Content/Scripts/FileBrowser.js#L256), and you can refer to and try to fix it via the solutions below.

Here is two solutions can help fixing it.

1. Like as @mohamed-jebri said, to update your Javascript code used in your page, and to change the value of `MAX_VIEW_ITEMS` via `window.localStorage['maxViewItems'] = 350`.
2. Generally on Azure for Webapp, it recommend to store and access a lot of asset files via Azure Blob Storage, please refer to [the offical document for PHP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-php?tabs=windows) to know how to use it. Meanwhile, for storing & fetching the metadata of asset file like filename or path, you can use [Azure Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-php?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: Actually I didn't check this answer yet because I removed all the files from that directory. I'll check it when I'll face this issue again and If it will be helpful I'll accept it. :)

Comment: @OwaisAslam Sure!